# Partial Motion Blur in Cycles

Tags: rendering, motion-blur

Is there a way to make Motion Blur to have effect only on certain objects?

Like if I want the main scene to be still and don't have a blur while camera moving, but all the other object want to be blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if feasible for your project, but you could parent all your objects in the scene to an empty and move the empty instead of the camera.
Also, turn on motion blur in your render settings and turn it off for the individual objects that you don't want blurred. (In the Object Properties Panel)

Comment: It worked. I've just turned off Motion Blur for all the main scene objects and they are not blurry. I didn't know it is possible to do in the Object Properties Panel. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help! :)